# How to duplicate keys and values in hash

Tags: ruby

I want to make a random number generator. I want the result to be:

```
"Your results are: 7, 7, 7"
```

This is my code:

```
random = 3.times.map {Random.new.rand(0..10000)}
puts random #Results ====> 180, 91, 300
@duh={}
random.map {|x|
  case x
    when 1..3000
      @duh["7"]=10000 #Jackpot
    when 3001..6000
      @duh["Cherries"]=500
    when 6001..10000
      @duh["Diamond"]=400
  end
}
puts "Your results are: #{@duh.keys.join(", ")}!"
```

The number results were `180, 91, 300`. It gave me one `7`. How do I keep my three `7`s?

Comment: Seems like you are only trying to use the keys, but do not use the values. Perhaps an array might suit your better?

Comment: It does seem like you're using the wrong data structure here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `map` here, but not in the right way:

```
numbers = 3.times.map { Random.new.rand(0..10000) }

prizes = numbers.map do |x|
  case x
  when 1..3000
    [ '7', 10000 ]
  when 3001..6000
    [ "Cherries", 500 ]
  when 6001..10000
    [ "Diamond", 400 ]
  end
end

puts "Your results are: #{prizes.collect { |p| p[0] }.join(", ")}!"
```

The only reason to use `map` is if you're interested in the results of that operation. Otherwise use `each` which is faster since it doesn't care about the result of each iteration.

Remember that in a Hash you can have a given key only once. Assigning the same value to `7` over and over means there is only one 7 key.

Comment: Wait, how do I find the first, second, and the third choices, so that I can do ``if firstchoice==secondchoice && secondchoice==thirdchoice`` ?

Comment: @Charles That's a different question, so try and post it as one. It keeps the answers focused.